# MongoDB (Node) findOne function does not return results when searching by ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

He guys, I really don't get what I'm doing wrong. Tried everything I could find on the interwebs but I can not get documents by ID in my Node application. So here is the situation:

If I use the MongoDB shell in the terminal this produces:

```
db.tochten.find({"_id" : ObjectId("577a6640c27dc10de81b265d")})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("577a6640c27dc10de81b265d"), "datum" : "2016-07-07", "weergavedatum" : "donderdag 7 juli", "begintijd" : "20:00", "eindtijd" : "21:00", "schip" : "Ouwe Dirk", "tocht" : "Rondvaart", "maxaantal" : "40", "opemerkingen" : "", "reserveringen" : [ ] }
```

So far so good right?

Inside my Node app

```
//open db connection
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
assert.equal(null, err);

// Set our collection
var col = db.collection('tochten');

//objectid stuff
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var o_id = new ObjectId("577a6640c27dc10de81b265d");

col.findOne({_id:o_id},function(err, docs) {
      console.log("Printing docs from Array. count " +      JSON.stringify(docs));
    });

db.close();

});
```

Produces null. I really breaking my head on this one. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You get `err` or `docs = null`?

Comment: Docs. Not printing the err. I will try that. edit: no error.

Comment: Please try with quotes around _id `col.findOne({"_id":o_id}`;

Comment: No difference. Same result.

Comment: If you run it with `find({}, function(err,docs){})`, do you get any results? I mean if even that doesn't work, your query might not be pointed to the correct collection.

Comment: It returns a long object. I think it's called a crusor, but don't really understand what it means.

Comment: This is a small part of it: { numberOfRetries: 5,
     tailableRetryInterval: 500,
     currentNumberOfRetries: 5,
     state: 0,
     streamOptions: {},
     bson: {},
     ns: 'booking.tochten',
     cmd: 
      { find: 'booking.tochten',
        limit: 0,
        skip: 0,
        query: {},
        slaveOk: true,
        readPreference: [Object] },
     options: 
      { skip: 0,
        limit: 0,
        raw: undefined,
        hint: null,
        timeout: undefined,
        slaveOk: true,

Comment: Is this the value you get if you print `docs`? If so, I don't think you are getting valid results.

Comment: Yes. This is a simple console.log(docs);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're closing the database before the result has arrived:

```
col.findOne({_id:o_id},function(err, docs) {
  console.log("Printing docs from Array. count " + JSON.stringify(docs));
});

db.close(); // <-- here!
```

Instead, close the database *once* the result has arrived:

```
col.findOne({_id:o_id},function(err, docs) {
  console.log("Printing docs from Array. count " + JSON.stringify(docs));
  db.close();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Won't be making this stupid mistake again. :D